# PHP Upgrade from 5.4 to 7.2

Tags: php-7.2, php-5.4

I am upgrading the PHP version used for a project. Used PHP Code Sniffer to find possible issues with PHP 7.2. How to resolve the following issue ?

1) `$this->mbstring_overload = ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2;`

INI directive 'mbstring.func_overload' is deprecated since PHP 7.2.

2) `$s->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);`

Global variable '$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' is deprecated since PHP 5.6 and removed since PHP 7.0; Use php://input instead

3) `$this->asp_tags = (ini_get('asp_tags') != '0');`
INI directive 'asp_tags' is removed since PHP 7.0. 
Since this is removed in PHP 7.0, what is the alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) if (function_exists('mb_strlen') && ((int)ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2)){ $this->mbstring_overload = ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2; }
2) $s->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: `$this->mbstring_overload = if (function_exists('mb_strlen') && ((int)ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2))`   Should it be like this ?

Comment: Hi @Alpy, I have this line in my code. Can you tell me, how to fix this?                `if (isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) && mb_strlen($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']))`

Comment: just remove the full if condition since this is deprecated and not asked by another condition